# Can't import local python modules when running on android

Tags: python, android, module, local, buildozer

I have a python project, which I've used kivy for UI and buildozer to build the apk (first time for me). I want to deploy my first application to my android phone. When I build and run using 'buildozer android debug deploy run logcat', the application shuts down instantly after it builds and runs with a module can't be found error.

I've tried a few things like moving main.py to libs directory, or using relative imports. But I don't think I've found the right combination. I also find that **init**.py never works for me, I've always just used work around to get modules to work. Like pip install -e . with a setup.py file.

My project directory structure is:

```
|--familybudget/
    |--.buildozer/
    |--__init__.py
    |--main.py
    |--libs/
        |--__init__.py
        |--account.py
        |--user.py
        |--controller.py
        |--...(more modules)...
        |--screens/
            |--__init__.py
            |--welcome_screen.py
            |--welcome_screen.kv
            |--..(more modules and kv files)..
```

My main.py looks like this (except for a few extra lines which were some extra screens):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.9.9
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Standard library imports
import sys
import os

# Third party imports
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp

# Local application imports
from libs.screens.welcome_screen import WelcomeScreen
from libs.screens.dashboard import Dashboard

class BudgetApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        screen_manager.add_widget(WelcomeScreen(name='welcome_screen'))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Dashboard(name='dashboard'))
        
        return screen_manager
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    BudgetApp().run()
```

My buildozer.spec file looks like this:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Family Budget

# (str) Package name
package.name = familybudget

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = test.familybudget

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,ttf,libs,libs/screens

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
# Do not prefix with './'
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3==3.9.9,Kivy==2.1.0,kivymd==1.1.1,psycopg2==2.9.6,openssl

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (list) Supported orientations
# Valid options are: landscape, portrait, portrait-reverse or landscape-reverse
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (string) Presplash animation using Lottie format.
# see https://lottiefiles.com/ for examples and https://airbnb.design/lottie/
# for general documentation.
# Lottie files can be created using various tools, like Adobe After Effect or Synfig.
#android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"

# (str) Adaptive icon of the application (used if Android API level is 26+ at runtime)
#icon.adaptive_foreground.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_fg.png
#icon.adaptive_background.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_bg.png

# (list) Permissions
# (See https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/buildoptions/#build-options-1 for all the supported syntaxes and properties)
#android.permissions = android.permission.INTERNET, (name=android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;maxSdkVersion=18)

# (list) features (adds uses-feature -tags to manifest)
#android.features = android.hardware.usb.host

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 31

# (int) Minimum API your APK / AAB will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 31

# (str) Android NDK version to use
android.ndk = 25b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Full name including package path of the Java class that implements Android Activity
# use that parameter together with android.entrypoint to set custom Java class instead of PythonActivity
#android.activity_class_name = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Extra xml to write directly inside the <manifest> element of AndroidManifest.xml
# use that parameter to provide a filename from where to load your custom XML code
#android.extra_manifest_xml = ./src/android/extra_manifest.xml

# (str) Extra xml to write directly inside the <manifest><application> tag of AndroidManifest.xml
# use that parameter to provide a filename from where to load your custom XML arguments:
#android.extra_manifest_application_arguments = ./src/android/extra_manifest_application_arguments.xml

# (str) Full name including package path of the Java class that implements Python Service
# use that parameter to set custom Java class which extends PythonService
#android.service_class_name = org.kivy.android.PythonService

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Put these files or directories in the apk assets directory.
# Either form may be used, and assets need not be in 'source.include_exts'.
# 1) android.add_assets = source_asset_relative_path
# 2) android.add_assets = source_asset_path:destination_asset_relative_path
#android.add_assets =

# (list) Put these files or directories in the apk res directory.
# The option may be used in three ways, the value may contain one or zero ':'
# Some examples:
# 1) A file to add to resources, legal resource names contain ['a-z','0-9','_']
# android.add_resources = my_icons/all-inclusive.png:drawable/all_inclusive.png
# 2) A directory, here  'legal_icons' must contain resources of one kind
# android.add_resources = legal_icons:drawable
# 3) A directory, here 'legal_resources' must contain one or more directories, 
# each of a resource kind:  drawable, xml, etc...
# android.add_resources = legal_resources
#android.add_resources =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (bool) Enable AndroidX support. Enable when 'android.gradle_dependencies'
# contains an 'androidx' package, or any package from Kotlin source.
# android.enable_androidx requires android.api >= 28
#android.enable_androidx = True

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_packaging_options =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Copy these files to src/main/res/xml/ (used for example with intent-filters)
#android.res_xml = PATH_TO_FILE,

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (str) screenOrientation to set for the main activity.
# Valid values can be found at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element
#android.manifest.orientation = fullSensor

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Android logcat only display log for activity's pid
#android.logcat_pid_only = False

# (str) Android additional adb arguments
#android.adb_args = -H host.docker.internal

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (list) The Android archs to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
# In past, was `android.arch` as we weren't supporting builds for multiple archs at the same time.
android.archs = arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

# (bool) enables Android auto backup feature (Android API >=23)
android.allow_backup = True

# (str) XML file for custom backup rules (see official auto backup documentation)
# android.backup_rules =

# (str) If you need to insert variables into your AndroidManifest.xml file,
# you can do so with the manifestPlaceholders property.
# This property takes a map of key-value pairs. (via a string)
# Usage example : android.manifest_placeholders = [myCustomUrl:\"org.kivy.customurl\"]
# android.manifest_placeholders = [:]

# (bool) Skip byte compile for .py files
# android.no-byte-compile-python = False

# (str) The format used to package the app for release mode (aab or apk or aar).
# android.release_artifact = aab

# (str) The format used to package the app for debug mode (apk or aar).
# android.debug_artifact = apk

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android URL to use for checkout
#p4a.url =

# (str) python-for-android fork to use in case if p4a.url is not specified, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android specific commit to use, defaults to HEAD, must be within p4a.branch
#p4a.commit = HEAD

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =

# Control passing the --use-setup-py vs --ignore-setup-py to p4a
# "in the future" --use-setup-py is going to be the default behaviour in p4a, right now it is not
# Setting this to false will pass --ignore-setup-py, true will pass --use-setup-py
# NOTE: this is general setuptools integration, having pyproject.toml is enough, no need to generate
# setup.py if you're using Poetry, but you need to add "toml" to source.include_exts.
#p4a.setup_py = false

# (str) extra command line arguments to pass when invoking pythonforandroid.toolchain
#p4a.extra_args =



#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.10.0

# (bool) Whether or not to sign the code
ios.codesign.allowed = false

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) The development team to use for signing the debug version
#ios.codesign.development_team.debug = <hexstring>

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s

# (str) The development team to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.development_team.release = <hexstring>

# (str) URL pointing to .ipa file to be installed
# This option should be defined along with `display_image_url` and `full_size_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.app_url =

# (str) URL pointing to an icon (57x57px) to be displayed during download
# This option should be defined along with `app_url` and `full_size_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.display_image_url =

# (str) URL pointing to a large icon (512x512px) to be used by iTunes
# This option should be defined along with `app_url` and `display_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.full_size_image_url =


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .aab, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

The catlog output is as follows (just did the last part of it because of character limit):

```
04-18 21:48:39.998 15669 15921 I python  : Android path ['.', '/data/user/0/test.familybudget.familybudget/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip', '/data/user/0/test.familybudget.familybudget/files/app/_python_bundle/modules', '/data/user/0/test.familybudget.familybudget/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages']
04-18 21:48:39.998 15669 15921 I python  : os.environ is environ({'PATH': '/product/bin:/apex/com.android.runtime/bin:/apex/com.android.art/bin:/system_ext/bin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/odm/bin:/vendor/bin:/vendor/xbin', 'ANDROID_BOOTLOGO': '1', 'ANDROID_ROOT': '/system', 'ANDROID_ASSETS': '/system/app', 'ANDROID_DATA': '/data', 'ANDROID_STORAGE': '/storage', 'ANDROID_ART_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.art', 'ANDROID_I18N_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.i18n', 'ANDROID_TZDATA_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.tzdata', 'EXTERNAL_STORAGE': '/sdcard', 'ASEC_MOUNTPOINT': '/mnt/asec', 'DOWNLOAD_CACHE': '/data/cache', 'SECONDARY_STORAGE': '/storage/sdcard:/storage/usb1:/storage/usb2', 'BOOTCLASSPATH': '/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-libart.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/okhttp.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/bouncycastle.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/framework-graphics.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/knoxsdk.jar:/system/framework/knoxanalyticssdk.jar:/system/framework/uibc_java.jar:/system/framework/SmpsManager.jar:/system/framework/esecomm.jar:/system/framework/sem-telephony-common.jar:/apex/com.android.i18n/javalib/core-icu4j.jar:/apex/com.android.appsearch/javalib/framework-appsearch.jar:/apex/com.android.conscrypt/javalib/conscrypt.jar:/apex/com.android.ipsec/javalib/android.net.ipsec.ike.jar:/apex/com.android.media/javalib/updatable-media.jar:/apex/com.android.mediaprovider/javalib/framework-mediaprovider.jar:/apex/com.android.os.statsd/javalib/framework-statsd.jar:/apex/com.android.permission/javalib/framework-permission.jar:/apex/com.android.permission/javalib/framework-permission-s.jar:/apex/com.android.scheduling/javalib/framework-scheduling.jar:/apex/com.android.sdkext/javalib/framework-sdkextensions.jar:/apex/com.android.tethering/javalib/framework-connectivity.jar:/apex/com.android.tethering/javalib/framework-tethering.jar:/apex/com.android.wifi/javalib/framework-wifi.jar:/apex/com.samsung.android.ipm/javalib/framework-samsung-ipm.jar:/apex/com.samsung.android.shell/javalib/framework-samsung-privilege.jar', 'DEX2OATBOOTCLASSPATH': '/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-libart.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/okhttp.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/bouncycastle.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/framework-graphics.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/knoxsdk.jar:/system/framework/knoxanalyticssdk.jar:/system/framework/uibc_java.jar:/system/framework/SmpsManager.jar:/system/framework/esecomm.jar:/system/framework/sem-telephony-common.jar:/apex/com.android.i18n/javalib/core-icu4j.jar', 'SYSTEMSERVERCLASSPATH': '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/ethernet-service.jar:/system/framework/ssrm.jar:/system/framework/semwifi-service.jar:/apex/com.android.appsearch/javalib/service-appsearch.jar:/apex/com.android.media/javalib/service-media-s.jar:/apex/com.android.permission/javalib/service-permission.jar:/apex/com.samsung.android.ipm/javalib/service-samsung-ipm.jar:/apex/com.samsung.android.shell/javalib/service-samsung-privilege.jar', 'KNOX_STORAGE': '/data/knox/ext_sdcard', 'ENC_EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET': '/storage/enc_emulated', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote': '17', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_usap_pool_primary': '19', 'ANDROID_ENTRYPOINT': 'main.pyc', 'ANDROID_ARGUMENT': '/data/user/0/test.familybudget.familybudget/files/app', 'ANDROID_APP_PATH': '/data/user/0/test.familybudget.familybudget/files/app', 'ANDROID_PRIVATE': '/data/user/0/test.familybudget.familybudget/files', 'ANDROID_UNPACK': '/data/user/0/test.familybudget.familybudget/files/app', 'PYTHONHOME': '/data/user/0/test.familybudget.familybudget/files/app', 'PYTHONPATH': '/data/user/0/te
04-18 21:48:39.998 15669 15921 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
04-18 21:48:39.998 15669 15921 I python  : AND: Ran string
04-18 21:48:39.998 15669 15921 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
04-18 21:48:40.078 15669 15921 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 24)
04-18 21:48:40.079 15669 15921 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
04-18 21:48:40.081 15669 15921 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/test.familybudget.familybudget/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_23-04-18_0.txt
04-18 21:48:40.081 15669 15921 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
04-18 21:48:40.081 15669 15921 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/test.familybudget.familybudget/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
04-18 21:48:40.081 15669 15921 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.9 (main, Apr 18 2023, 21:45:42)
04-18 21:48:40.081 15669 15921 I python  : [Clang 14.0.6 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 4c603efb
04-18 21:48:40.081 15669 15921 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at ""
04-18 21:48:40.081 15669 15921 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
04-18 21:48:40.082 15669 15921 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
04-18 21:48:40.623 15669 15921 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
04-18 21:48:40.772 15669 15921 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
04-18 21:48:40.795 15669 15921 I python  : [INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 1.1.1, git-Unknown, 2023-04-17 (installed at "/data/user/0/test.familybudget.familybudget/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivymd/__init__.pyc")
04-18 21:48:40.800 15669 15921 I python  : [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
04-18 21:48:40.817 15669 15921 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
04-18 21:48:40.833 15669 15921 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
04-18 21:48:40.834 15669 15921 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
04-18 21:48:40.834 15669 15921 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 v1.r32p1-01bet2-mbs2v39_0.131801e953429f661ecce1d5e1d2b3ef'>
04-18 21:48:40.834 15669 15921 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'ARM'>
04-18 21:48:40.834 15669 15921 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Mali-G76'>
04-18 21:48:40.834 15669 15921 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
04-18 21:48:40.834 15669 15921 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16383>
04-18 21:48:40.835 15669 15921 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
04-18 21:48:40.871 15669 15921 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
04-18 21:48:40.872 15669 15921 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
04-18 21:48:40.916 15669 15921 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
04-18 21:48:40.916 15669 15921 I python  :    File "/tmp/tmpdc22fdzd/main.py", line 14, in <module>
04-18 21:48:40.916 15669 15921 I python  :  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libs'
04-18 21:48:40.916 15669 15921 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

Comment: This is killing me, softly.